# UNIX and LINUX bsub command -W limit

Tags: linux, bash, unix, lsf

I am trying to submit 10 jobs using bsub command on a specific location.

```
$ bsub -q alloc -P acc_CLASSNAME\
> -J "Array_#4[1-10]"\
> -o "Output.%I" -n 1\
> -W 2:00 $HOME/bash/count.sh 1
```

when I run this, I am keep getting an error

```
   Run limit must be specified using bsub -W.
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Request aborted by esub. Job not submitted.
```

I am not sure why I am getting such error because I clearly limited the time with -W command on the last line.
Can some one please help me to fix this problem?

Thank you

update with prepended commands -

```
$ bash -x bsub -q alloc -P acc_BSR1015
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ case "$-" in
+ __lmod_vx=x
+ '[' -n x ']'
+ set +x
```

```
 bash -x -W 120 $HOME/bash/count.sh 1
bash: -W: invalid option
Usage:  bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
    bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
```

Comment: If you prepend that command line with  `echo ` , what does it print?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, `echo` isn't a great tool for this kind of thing -- you can't tell the difference between output of `echo "one word"` and `echo "one" "word"`, even though they're completely different commands. Better to suggest `set -x`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True, but unless `$HOME` has spaces in the path, there shouldn't be any spaces except those already visible. Any extra space would be an error.

Comment: echo '-W 2:00 $HOME/bash/count.sh 1'
-W 2:00 $HOME/bash/count.sh 1

Comment: @HyominSeo, ...are you saying that there are _literal single quote characters_ in the `echo` output? That's a surprising result. It's also surprising if the output contains `$HOME` instead of containing an actual path. If that's _not_ what you mean to say, maybe edit that information into the question itself (so all the formatting tools are available) instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: @HyominSeo Please prepend the full command line with `echo ` so we see the command close to what it looks to the OS - or rather, do what Charles suggests above and below :-) Put the result in the question so we can see it clearly.

Comment: (and I really do recommend `bash -x yourscript` as a better way to log what `yourscript` is trying to run).

Comment: i ve added the bash -x prepended results, which says aht -W is invalid option

Comment: @Rivendel Did you solve it? If not, please provide the info we asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your cluster administrator.  Esub is a feature that allows the cluster admin to check the incoming request and reject it if it doesn't meet the site policies.